# Is it possible to use anonymous locations data from the maps app?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-gps

After much researching, I have not found an answer to my question. Which is, is it possible to use anonymous geolocation data from google or google maps to determine a users location who don't have my app installed. My end goal is to determine whether a user without my app has parked their car or not. Google Now is able to notify the user where he or she parked their car. I would like to know if there is any method of using that collection of data for my app.

Answer (score 0):

To get user location "determine a users location who don't have my app installed" you will still need a way to get that user location from either Google Maps (Can user intent for result) or Browser (JS), GPS/WIFI/Network (Fine/Coarse Location) and the user has to explicitly grant permission or share his or her location, otherwise its a security breach and illegal to user privacy to gather their information such as location without there prior consent.

Either you have an App to get the location from Google Maps or a Web App to gather location from Web browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Google would not release this information to the public even if they had it. There are various reasons for this - privacy and legal concerns are two that stick out.

I can't see any way it would be possible to gather this data except asking the users themselves to collect this information. Neither the user nor the person being spied on would likely receive this well!